# guake can not start on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, guake

I have upgrade my os from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10, but after that `guake` can not be started. And I wonder if so, How can I draw back to 15.04?

If run guake in terminal

```
    ➜  ~  guake
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py", line 27, in <module>
        import dbus
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
        import dbus.types as types
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
        from _dbus_bindings import (
    ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8
```

run command `apt-cache policy python`

```
➜  ~  apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.9-1
  Candidate: 2.7.9-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.9-1 0
        500 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
➜  ~
```

Comment: What error message did you get if you run `guake` in a terminal ?

Comment: @hg8,I have edited my question

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy python`

Comment: @A.B., hi, I added the output of  `apt-cache policy python`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. The output of `apt-cache policy guake`